# Bootstrap panels won't collapse after expand in Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

When I expand a collapsible Bootstrap panel it opens but won't close when I click the same parent panel again. This is evident on the "RESIDENTIAL" panel and the nav-collapse at xs screen size.

It works properly in the HTML (non-WordPress version) of the site, but when I transferred it into PHP for Wordpress it stopped working. I've researched a good bit but can't find anything on this issue. Thanks for any advice or help.

Wordpress Site (broken panel collapse): http://parkerrichard.com/studiogreen/wordpress/project-01/

HTML Site (working panel collapse): http://parkerrichard.com/studiogreen/html/project-01.html

HTML:

```
<aside class="navbar-collapse collapse panel-group col-lg-3 col-med-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    RESIDENTIAL
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
          <li class="drop"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down nav-caret"></span></li>
          <li><a href="studiogreen/wordpress/project-01/">PROJECT <span class="spaced">1</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="studiogreen/wordpress/project-01/">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">2</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="studiogreen/wordpress/project-01/">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">3</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="studiogreen/wordpress/project-01/">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">4</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="studiogreen/wordpress/project-01/">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">5</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="studiogreen/wordpress/project-01/">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">6</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="studiogreen/wordpress/project-01/">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">7</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="studiogreen/wordpress/project-01/">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">8</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="studiogreen/wordpress/project-01/">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">9</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="studiogreen/wordpress/project-01/">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">10</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a href="schools.html">
          SCHOOLS
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a href="parks.html">
          PARKS
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a href="hospitality.html">
          HOSPITALITY
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>        
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFive">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive">
          ELEMENTS
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFive">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
          <li class="drop"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down nav-caret"></span></li>
          <li><a href="plants.html">ENTRY</a></li>
          <li><a href="plants.html">FENCES</a></li>
          <li><a href="plants.html">FIRE</a></li>
          <li><a href="plants.html">LIGHTING</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="plants.html">PAVING</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="plants.html">PLANTS</a></li>
          <li><a href="plants.html">POOLS</a></li>
          <li><a href="plants.html">SEATING</a></li>
          <li><a href="plants.html">SCULPTURE</a></li>
          <li><a href="plants.html">STAIRS</a></li>
          <li><a href="plants.html">SUSTAINABILITY</a></li>
          <li><a href="plants.html">WATER</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</aside>
```

CSS:

```
/*
* Left aside av
 */

.panel {
  border: 0px;
  -webkit-bo-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.0);
  bo-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(00,,0);
  margin: 4px 0 0 100px;
}
  .panel-title {
  fontsize: 14px;
  lette-spacing: 2px;    font-weight: 600;    color: #555;
  paddig-top: 7px;
  paddig-otom: 7px;
  list-tyle: none;
}

.paneltil a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
  .panel-default > .panel-heading{
  background-color: transpret
  border-colo: transparent;
}

panel-body {
  margi-left: -25px;
  marin-top: -22px;
  paddig-top: 0px;
  paddin-btom: 0px;
  paddin-left: 0px;
}

.panelboyul {
  list-style-tye: none;
}

.pane-body ul li {
  paddingtop: 10px;
  padding-bttm 10px;
  letterspacing: 1px;
}

.pnl-group {
  text-align: left;
}

.panel-group .panel-headin + .panel-collaps >.anel-body {
border-top:0px;
}

.nav-caret {
  pading-left: 10px;
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

Comment: respond.min.js missing in your wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @vel. You were correct that respond.js wasn't being loaded but I believe I have fixed that and still the menus will not collapse. Any thoughts?